# Checking if a contents fall into an adjacent pair and summing

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate a sum of the value volume if:

1.) region[i] = region[i+1]

Example:

region[1] = "AXB"
region[2] = "AXB"

So for instance in this case it should return

```
   value[i] = value[i] + value[i+1]
```

2.) If one is not true the code should check to see if region[i] = region[i+1] is an adjacent region defined by Adjacent1, Adjacent2, etc.

Example:
region[1] = "AXB"
region[2] = "CDB"

This would be adjacent and the value should be summed:

```
   value[i] = value[i] + value[i+1]
```

Note this is for my own personal use and not for a HW assignment. 
I've coded the following so far as a start, but not sure where to go from here.

```
a = c(15,6,10,50)
region = c("AXB","AXB","CBD","FLR")
value = c(10,20,15,30)

df = data.frame(a,region,value)

Adjacent1 = c("AXB", "CBD")
Adjacent2 = c("DMN','FLR")

for(i in 1:length(df$region))
 {
     if (region[i] == region[i+1]) {
      df$value[i]  = value[i] + value[i+1]
      }
 }
```

gives me an error:

```
Error in if (region[i] == region[i + 1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

**Expected Output:**

```
a    region value leadregion  valueNew
15    AXB    10   AXB           30
6     AXB    20   CBD           45
10    CBD    15                 
50    FLR    30   FLR           30
```

Comment: Think about what you are calculating. What happens when `i = 4`? It tries to compare "FLR" to... `region[5]`. Which does not exist. You could try `1:(length(region)-1)`.

Comment: following @Roman's comment, you could also change the loop from `1:length(df$region)` to `2:length(df$region)` and subtract 1 from the indices.

Comment: Can you add expected output for your example data, not clear what step 2 is doing.

Comment: Hello zx8754, I just added what I was expecting for the expected output. I ran your line and it gave me an error. --> Error: could not find function "if_else". Any thoughts? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are subsetting a non-existing value of `region[5]`. You have several options.

As mentioned by the gentleperson from the comment section, you can start from 2. position and use substraction to index elements, something along the lines of

```
for (i in 2:length(df$region)) {
  if (region[i-1] == region[i]) {
    df$value[i-1] <- sum(value[c(i-1, i)])
  }
}
```

Another option is to stop 1 element before the end of the vector, which will now accomodate `i+1` to not return an `NA`.

```
for (i in 1:(length(df$region) - 1)) {
  if (region[i] == region[i+1]) {
    df$value[i] <- sum(value[c(i, i+1)])
  }
}
```

Comment: Roman, I ran your code and it worked exactly as you explained here. Any thoughts on how to look at adjacent items. For instance, I would like to sum AXB, and CBD together since their adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

Using lead lag from dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    region = as.character(region),
    regionLead = lead(region, default = ""),
    valueLead = lead(value, default = 0),
    valueNew = if_else(region == regionLead, 
                      value + valueLead, value))

#    a region value regionLead valueLead valueNew
# 1 15    AXB    10        AXB        20       30
# 2  6    AXB    20        CBD        15       20
# 3 10    CBD    15        FLR        30       15
# 4 50    FLR    30                    0       30
```